# Python Socket error

Tags: python, sockets, syntax-error

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a Server program.  However, when it comes time for the server to accept the socket connection, it won't and I have to terminate the program with

```
File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
  client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 195, in accept
  sock, addr = self._sock.accept() `
```

I'm pretty sure it is saying that something is not matching up but I cannot find out where it is not doing so.  My server program is below:

```
 import socket
 import os

 server_address = '10.1.1.2'

 #while 1:
 #       os.system('netcat -l 3333')
 serversocket = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

 serversocket.bind ((socket.gethostname(), 3333))

 serversocket.listen(1)

 serversocket, client_addr = serversocket.accept()
 print client_addr

 serversocket.close()
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: do you have a client to make the connection?  socket.accept() will hang until a client connects.

Comment: yes i do but its very basic so i didn't include it, but i has a socket.connect() statement so I'm assuming that makes the connection

Comment: I second TJD. I tested this out, and socket.accept() hangs until a client connects.

Comment: I figured it out.  Instead of socket.gethostname() I needed to be server_address in that spot.  Thats why I couldn't connect to the server in the first place and always had to kill it with ^C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of socket.gethostname() I needed to be server_address in that spot. Thats why I couldn't connect to the server in the first place and always had to kill it with ^C

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` instead of just `socket.gethostname()`.